# Xcode giving error Value of type 'FlutterViewController' has no member 'binaryMessenger' when writing ios native swift code in flutter project

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, native

I made a flutter project with command

```
flutter create -i swift myProject
```

then I changed the directory to myProject with
    cd myProject
and ther I run 
    pod setup.
It run swiftly but when I added code to AppDeligate.swift in ios/Runner/Runner directory according to the tutorial here:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Here is my AppDeligate.swift:

```
  @UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
  let batteryChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "samples.flutter.dev/battery",
                                            binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
  batteryChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
    (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
    // Note: this method is invoked on the UI thread.
    // Handle battery messages.
      })

return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

I am getting error "Value of type 'FlutterViewController' has no member 'binaryMessenger'"

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this line

```
let batteryChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "samples.flutter.dev/battery",
                                        binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
```

To ->

```
let batteryChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "samples.flutter.dev/battery",
                                        binaryMessenger: controller as! FlutterBinaryMessenger)
```

It was changed in latest flutter upgrade.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. This should be mentioned in the docs or somewhere. I tried everything but unable to figure out what was wrong for more than 5 days.

Answer (score 1):

When using Flutter MACOS platform this will not help, you need to use this code:

```
let batteryChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(
      name: "samples.flutter.dev/battery",
      binaryMessenger: controller.engine.binaryMessenger
)
```